# Sails JS CSRF Token is different every call

Tags: ajax, angular, sails.js, csrf

I want to enable CSRF in my SailsJS and Angular 2 application but I have been having endless problems.

The Angular app is on a page that is only accessible after a user has logged in, controlled by Sails policies.
Then I `http.get` the CSRF token from the `/csrfToken` route and store it, adding it to HTTP headers when doing a POST.

I was continually getting CSRF mismatch errors and I *finally* realised that the `/csrfToken` route was returning a different value every time, both from a `http.get` and also when accessing the URL from the browser.

It wasn't clear that this was happening when I went through [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/WKtmKha6Ehw) (see 00:30) for a multi-page application where the CSRF value is submitted as a hidden field in a form, and there doesn't seem to be any mention of how to change this behaviour in the Sails documentation.

How can I configure Sails so that it will maintain a single CSRF value for a session?

**UPDATE: It’s working now**

I have made my update an answer as advised.

Comment: Please edit and put your answer as answer to your own question and then choose it as approved answer. It will make question answered as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there were different issues that were causing my problems.

My code had become so fragmented that I didn’t realise I was referencing an older function that was putting the CSRF into the header wrong.

I rolled back a bunch of client-side code and then magically the CSRF value remained consistent between Ajax calls and also worked correctly in the POST request.

So I guess there was something in my fragmented code that had caused the CSRF token to change between API calls but I don’t know what it was.

Visiting `/csrfToken` in the browser still produces a different result every time but it does not seem to affect the API calls.

*EDIT*

I discovered that the CSRF changes with each request to `/csrfToken`. One of my mistakes was that after I stored the CSRF value the first time I then (accidentally) requested a new `/csrfToken` again later, which then invalidated the stored value. Using the stored value would then result in a CSRF mismatch error as a new value had been issued.